# Joomla reCaptcha reloading form instead of showing error

Tags: joomla, recaptcha, captcha

I built a website using Joomla and in my contact form I used Google's reCaptcha v.2. When the user checks the captcha, the form is sent correctly and the success message is displayed. However when the user does not check the captcha, the form is reloaded and the error is not displayed. On the console, I get an ajax containing:

> {"success":false,"message":"Please, fill the CAPTCHA.","messages":null,"data":null}

How can I keep the form filled and show the error message to the user?

Joomla version 3.9.0
Theme: flex - Joomshaper (paid theme. I got in touch with them but the support is horrible)
Contact form using Page builder - Joomshaper
reCaptcha v.2

Comment: Without the template it is difficult to tell which code needs to be modified.

Comment: Please share URL as well.